# How to add shadows to gradient border layer . refer the below image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How to add a shadow effect to this gradient border.

Here is the sample extension to create a border layer with a specified width. When I tried to add a shadow layer whole UI gets affected.

[image]

```
self.gradientBorder(width: 3, colors: UIColor.defaultGradient, andRoundCornersWithRadius: min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width))
```

extension UIView {

```
    private static let kLayerNameGradientBorder = "GradientBorderLayer"

    func gradientBorder(width: CGFloat,
                        colors: [UIColor],
                        startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0),
                        endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0),
                        andRoundCornersWithRadius cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0) {
        
        let existingBorder = gradientBorderLayer()
        let border = existingBorder ?? CAGradientLayer()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y,
                              width: bounds.size.width + width, height: bounds.size.height + width)
        border.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        border.startPoint = startPoint
        border.endPoint = endPoint
        
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        let maskRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + width/2, y: bounds.origin.y + width/2,
                              width: bounds.size.width - width, height: bounds.size.height - width)
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: maskRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        mask.path = path
        mask.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        mask.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mask.lineWidth = width
        mask.masksToBounds = false
        border.mask = mask
        

        let exists = (existingBorder != nil)
        if !exists {
            layer.addSublayer(border)
        }
    }
    
    private func gradientBorderLayer() -> CAGradientLayer? {
        let borderLayers = layer.sublayers?.filter { return $0.name == UIView.kLayerNameGradientBorder }
        if borderLayers?.count ?? 0 > 1 {
            fatalError()
        }
        return borderLayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why your old question got closed... Anyway, setting a shadow on the `mask` layer seems to work ok (I just set shadow - color/opacity/offset).

Comment: I tried, but the UI doesn't look nice

Comment: your code did not generate same out put that you shown

Comment: self.gradientBorder(width: 3, colors: UIColor.defaultGradient, andRoundCornersWithRadius: min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width))

Comment: @nickypatson We can never know what is 'not nice'. Can you share your _expected_ output (maybe a super crude mockup)?

Comment: @Alladinian I need to shadow like this 

https://uicookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Glowing-Gradient-Button.jpg

hope you understand

Comment: @nickypatson This is a glow effect (which I guess you could approximate with a .zero offset / large radius shadow but shadow afaik doesn't support multiple colors like in your example). Also, the view in your example is opaque.

Comment: @Alladinian okay then I don't need any gradient shadows, just a normal black shadows. How can I add to this layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Minor changes from initial code:

- background layer doesn't interfere with added subviews
- handles resizing correctly (when called in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`)

---

You can do this by adding a shadow properties to the view's layer, and adding another layer as a "background" layer.

After **Edit**... Here is your `UIView` extension - slightly modified (see the comments):

```
extension UIView {
    
    private static let kLayerNameGradientBorder = "GradientBorderLayer"
    private static let kLayerNameBackgroundLayer = "BackgroundLayer"

    func gradientBorder(width: CGFloat,
                        colors: [UIColor],
                        startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0),
                        endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0),
                        andRoundCornersWithRadius cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0,
                        bgColor: UIColor = .white,
                        shadowColor: UIColor = .black,
                        shadowRadius: CGFloat = 5.0,
                        shadowOpacity: Float = 0.75,
                        shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
                        ) {
        
        let existingBackground = backgroundLayer()
        let bgLayer = existingBackground ?? CALayer()
        
        bgLayer.name = UIView.kLayerNameBackgroundLayer

        // set its color
        bgLayer.backgroundColor = bgColor.cgColor
        
        // insert at 0 to not cover other layers
        if existingBackground == nil {
            layer.insertSublayer(bgLayer, at: 0)
        }

        // use same cornerRadius as border
        bgLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        // inset its frame by 1/2 the border width
        bgLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: width * 0.5, dy: width * 0.5)

        // set shadow properties
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset

        let existingBorder = gradientBorderLayer()
        let border = existingBorder ?? CAGradientLayer()
        
        border.name = UIView.kLayerNameGradientBorder
        
        // don't do this
//      border.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y,
//                            width: bounds.size.width + width, height: bounds.size.height + width)

        // use this instead
        border.frame = bounds

        border.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        border.startPoint = startPoint
        border.endPoint = endPoint
        
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        let maskRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + width/2, y: bounds.origin.y + width/2,
                              width: bounds.size.width - width, height: bounds.size.height - width)
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: maskRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        mask.path = path
        mask.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        mask.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mask.lineWidth = width
        mask.masksToBounds = false
        border.mask = mask
        
        let exists = (existingBorder != nil)
        if !exists {
            layer.addSublayer(border)
        }
        
    }

    private func backgroundLayer() -> CALayer? {
        let aLayers = layer.sublayers?.filter { return $0.name == UIView.kLayerNameBackgroundLayer }
        if aLayers?.count ?? 0 > 1 {
            fatalError()
        }
        return aLayers?.first
    }

    private func gradientBorderLayer() -> CAGradientLayer? {
        let borderLayers = layer.sublayers?.filter { return $0.name == UIView.kLayerNameGradientBorder }
        if borderLayers?.count ?? 0 > 1 {
            fatalError()
        }
        return borderLayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer
    }
}
```

After **Edit**... and here's an example in-use:

```
class GradBorderViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var topGradView: UIView = UIView()
    
    // make bottom grad view a button
    var botGradView: UIButton = UIButton()

    var topBkgView: UIView = UIView()
    var botBkgView: UIView = UIView()
    
    let embededLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        embededLabel.textColor = .red
        embededLabel.textAlignment = .center
        embededLabel.text = "Label as subview"
        
        botGradView.setTitle("Button", for: [])
        botGradView.setTitleColor(.red, for: [])
        botGradView.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)

        topGradView.backgroundColor = .clear
        botGradView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        topBkgView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        botBkgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

        [topBkgView, topGradView, botBkgView, botGradView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        embededLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // embed label in topGradView
        topGradView.addSubview(embededLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // yellow background view on top half, dark-red background view on bottom half
            topBkgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            topBkgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            botBkgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            botBkgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            topBkgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            botBkgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            topBkgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            botBkgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBkgView.bottomAnchor),

            // each grad border view 75% of width, 80-pt constant height
            topGradView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBkgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            topGradView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            
            botGradView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topGradView.widthAnchor),
            botGradView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topGradView.heightAnchor),

            // center each grad border view in a background view
            topGradView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBkgView.centerXAnchor),
            topGradView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBkgView.centerYAnchor),

            botGradView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botBkgView.centerXAnchor),
            botGradView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botBkgView.centerYAnchor),

            // center the embedded label in the topGradView
            embededLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topGradView.centerXAnchor),
            embededLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topGradView.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])

        botGradView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.testTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func testTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        print("Tapped!")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        let a1: [CGFloat] = [173, 97, 222].map({$0 / 255.0})
        let a2: [CGFloat] = [0, 198, 182].map({$0 / 255.0})
        let c1 = UIColor(red: a1[0], green: a1[1], blue: a1[2], alpha: 1.0)
        let c2 = UIColor(red: a2[0], green: a2[1], blue: a2[2], alpha: 1.0)

        topGradView.gradientBorder(width: 6,
                                   colors: [c1, c2],
                                   startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
                                   endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0),
                                   andRoundCornersWithRadius: topGradView.frame.height * 0.5
        )
        
        botGradView.gradientBorder(width: 6,
                               colors: [c1, c2],
                               startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
                               endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0),
                               andRoundCornersWithRadius: topGradView.frame.height * 0.5,
                               shadowColor: .white,
                               shadowRadius: 12,
                               shadowOpacity: 0.95,
                               shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        )
        
    }
    
}
```

After **Edit**... Results:

[image]

Comment: it's working perfectly but this view is meant for UIButton, UIbutton title is not showing

Comment: if I add this extension to a UIView, the subviews of UIviews are hidden

Comment: @nickypatson - for future reference... When posting here on Stack Overflow, it's best to post your **full, actual** question, as opposed to *"this is part of what I want"* ... too often get's followed (as in this case) with: *"well, ok, but it's not doing what I really want"*. Also, instead of commenting with *"it's not working when I do [this]"*, try to fix it and comment with whatever you did to fix it or explain what's not working. See my edited answer.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/n6qQRrj.png -- here is the sample image 

@DonMag - I will keep this in mind

Comment: yeah that perfect, it's working perfectly

Thanks for your time